# How to add textbox and dropdownlist to checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

i want to provide a list of ability for user to choose (by checkbox list and the option retrieve from table). if user tick the checkbox, the related textbox and dropdownlist will enable to let user input and choose.

how can i add textbox and dropdownlist to checkboxlist ? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Checkboxlist. For this u have to use gridview and design template as per your need. You can check this links.http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource14-Dropdown-checkbox-and-textbox-controls-in-aspnet-editable-Gridview.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/169942/what-is-a-templatefield-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-and-ho.aspx